# Power spectrum from image gives peak at the same position for different images

Tags: python

I copied a code for analysing the power spectrum of an image and adapted it to my needs. My problem consists on the fact that on different images I get always a peak at same frequencies, even from images where the peak should be at different values.

That's the piece of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
 
img = mpimg.imread("image.png")
npix = image.shape[0]
img.shape[0] == img.shape[1]
 

f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
mag = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))

n = int( math.ceil(img.shape[0] / 2.) * 2 )

a = np.fft.rfft(img,n, axis=0)

a = a.real*a.real + a.imag*a.imag
a = a.sum(axis=1)/a.shape[1]

f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n)

n = int( math.ceil(img.shape[1] / 2.) * 2 )

a = np.fft.rfft(img,n,axis=1)

a = a.real*a.real + a.imag*a.imag

a = a.sum(axis=0)/a.shape[0]

f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n)

plt.plot(f[1:],a[1:])

plt.ylabel( 'Amplitude' )
plt.xlabel( 'Resolution' )
plt.yscale( 'log' )
plt.legend()
```

[image: Final_Result]

No matter which image I give, I get this peak around 0.18

Here are two examples of images that I used for producing the spectra:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you "give" a different image? Maybe the code uses the same image each time? And if not, maybe the peak at 0.18 is correct? How do you know which value should be correct instead?

Comment: seems like it is giving the correct result, both images have a sine wave at that frequency.

Comment: What I do is just to load in Jupyter the new image and give it to the code. I know as a fact that the second image that I show has a value of circa 0.22  (published in academic literature)

Comment: Here is the reference: https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-022-32039-z
In detail look for figure 1

Comment: well, can you include the imports ? ... it's hard to debug without the imports.

Comment: Sorry I forgot them

Answer (score 0):

the second image has been rescaled up to (328, 328), if you scale it down to the same size as the first image (256,256) you will get the correct answer, when working with images and spatial frequencies know that scaling up in space (number of pixels) is scaling down in the spatial frequency domain.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(r'ptma2.png')
img = img.resize((256, 256))  # rescale it down to (256,256) again
img = np.asarray(img)  # Get array back
f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
mag = 20 * np.log(np.abs(fshift))

n = int(math.ceil(img.shape[0] / 2.) * 2)

a = np.fft.rfft(img, n, axis=0)

a = a.real * a.real + a.imag * a.imag
a = a.sum(axis=1) / a.shape[1]

f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n)

n = int(math.ceil(img.shape[1] / 2.) * 2)

a = np.fft.rfft(img, n, axis=1)

a = a.real * a.real + a.imag * a.imag

a = a.sum(axis=0) / a.shape[0]

f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n)

plt.plot(f[1:], a[1:])

plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.xlabel('Resolution')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]